# Does studying other people's programs help in self growth?

Tags: learning, programming-practices, coding-style, code-reviews, source-code

*Should* I be *studying* big softwares written by other people in our company? My work may be a small sub module on the top of that software, and I may not be required to know what goes beneath the hood,

*but*

**Does understanding other people's code grow my knowledge about programming methods or anything else?**

Comment: Understading well written code - yes. Understanding any code might give you a headache and very little benefit.

Comment: @CodeWorks: not sure. If you read ONLY crap code, you probably won't learn much from it. If you read a mixture of good and bad code, you'll probably learn more from it. Similarly, for a different domain, Stephen King says in his memoirs on writing that recommends to read bad novels. You can't appreciate the good ones if you don't read bad ones, and there's a whole breadth and range of ways to approach writing. You might be surprised by what you find in the bad ones.

Comment: understanding other people's code (assuming its well written) will definitely help u to earn knowledge about methods and flows... but just don't copy that code.. implement in ur own way in ur own flow to get rid on it...

Comment: @haylem: I always though Stephen King's books WERE the bad ones. :)

Comment: @pdr: Arguably, and he himself does NOT defend it as great litterature, that I know of. I don't find him always very consistent. Think he's got a thing to paint an individual psychological state though. And a kid's mental state as well. Grown-ups tend to not have that ability, that always surprised me with him. Prefer the novels that are more psych-based than supernatural-based. Screenplays are pretty good too, by judging by the number of them on the IMDb 250 list... Found the memoirs quite interesting, whether you like his style or not.

Comment: @haylem: And there have been some good movies made from his books, particularly by Darabont. But I maintain his only truly excellent book was Insomnia, where he refrained from getting too tied up in psychology.

Comment: @pdr: Had a very intersting build-up, but I found the end left me a bit thinking "meh". Most disappointing for me amongst the latest one was "From a Buick 8", which I found very messy and re-using old tricks, though apparently it was a huge success. I do like that he ventures in different genres though. Liked most of the Bachman books I read, too, though he doesn't like most of them himself.

Comment: Learn to Read the Source, Luke: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## In General: Learn from the Contrast

I think it's important to both read good and bad code.

If you read ONLY crap code, you probably won't learn much from it. If you read a mixture of good and bad code, you'll probably learn more from it. The good code is supposed to teach you new things, the bad code to show you the general mindset of the average programmer and the pitfalls to avoid, and to make you realize how much effort can be saved with good code.

The contrast is very important in helping.

Similarly, for a different domain, Stephen King says in his memoirs on writing that recommends to read bad novels. You can't appreciate the good ones if you don't read bad ones, and there's a whole breadth and range of ways to approach writing. You might be surprised by what you find in the bad ones.

That being said, don't spend your life reading code that looks like it's been written by a herd of monkeys or bored students with no interest in learning programming and who just an one CS elective (except if that's your job, then it's helpful to learn their common errors and to understand why they occur frequently).

It's very important to compare and contrast. For instance, take the source code for the 3 major BSD systems: NetBSD, OpenBSD and FreeBSD. They are very similar, yet their implementations of even the simplest tools differ (`ls`, `cat`, etc...). And surely there's one you'll prefer over the other (haven't checked for about 8 years, and not wanting to be judgmental here, I just want to give a personal experience, but at the time the OpenBSD code struck me as largely more elegant than the others, and the NetBSD code to be quite instructive to learn about using macros and pre-proc guards).

## For In-House Code: Learn from the Context

You mention that it's about reading code written within your company as well. In this case, I'd say it's even more important to read some of it. It's very interesting for you to get an understanding of the team's mindset by looking at the code, but it will also give you a deeper understanding of how your programs work.

Finally, there's a very historical component to it. Don't just read the current codebase. Give your favorite SCM client at hand and lurk through the timeline of the codebase. It's sometimes very interesting to see why a code became to be what it is now. It can have gone through the hands of a dozen different programmers of different age, or you can even see that a single programmer might have matured over time. It also teaches you about certain "oddities" and mean sneaky bugs they might have encountered and why they chose an approach over another, even if seemingly less elegant.

It gives you context.

Comment: Ah, is it like writing critiques on other's photographs helps us to be better photographers?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I don't do much photography, and I'd be weary of making analogies (even the one I made), but I'd assume it's probably true as well. It's important to learn to critique, whether it's about books, movies, photographs, code... It's important to not just keep your critiques to yourself though: the second step is to expose your ideas and confront them with others, and you may realize they weren't that good in the first place, instead of maintaining the same views for years, safe from any external review.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely. Studying and understanding other peoples code is absolutely essential in order to grow as a programmer.

In a general sense, it is always good to study and understand other peoples code, even code which is not part of the system your are working on. This will help you to see things which are good and bad in your own system, and inspire you to think up new and better ways to improve your own code.

Having a basic knowledge of the entire system you are working on -- not only the components you are responsible for -- is important in order to know how you can interact with other parts of the system.

Comment: Can we assume that their code is not well written?

Comment: I'm not assuming anything. If the code is crap, you will still need to know how the crap code works, even if you probably shouldn't take too much inspiration from the crap code into your code. Then again, who decides if it is crap code?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, Each programmer/developer can write code in their own ways and learned ways. Learning/analyzing other's code is one of the reason to become a better developer. In others code

1. somebody follows coding standard
2. somebody follows junk code
3. somebody follows short codes like in framework
4. somebody follows all of the above

Learners types:

1. Listening learners
2. Seeing learners
3. Touch / experience learners